# Redirect to specific page when a gridview buttonfield is clicked

Tags: asp.net

I have two fields in my gridview.  One is a field with a date range and one of them is a buttonfield. I want to make it so that when a button is clicked, it will redirect them to a specific page with a formatted string similar to how it's done when a hyperlinkfield is clicked as such:

`DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductInfo.aspx?ProductID={0}"`

However, I don't want to use the other field's value(the date range).  I want to use the primary key of the record which is "SundayOfWeek".  The user wants a button rather than a hyperlink.  Is there a way I can do the same thing with a button?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this type of column instead of a ButtonField:

```
<Columns>
   <asp:HyperLinkField 
     DataTextField="ProductName" 
     HeaderText="Product Name" 
     SortExpression="ProductName" 
     DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductID" 
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductInfo.aspx?ProductID={0}" />
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, one of many ways is this:

```
 <columns>
      <asp:templatefield headertext="Button">
        <itemtemplate>
          <asp:Button id="btnRedirect"
            Text= "Click me"
            CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SundayOfWeek")%>'
            OnClick="DoRedirect"
            runat="server"/> 
        </itemtemplate>
      </asp:templatefield>
    </columns>


protected void DoRedirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button theButton = sender as Button;
    Response.Redirect("Newpage.aspx?ID="+theButton.CommandArgument);
}
```

Comment: Would there also be a way to do the same thing with jQuery?

Comment: Definitely, but how exactly do you want to do this with jQuery? Tim's answer already shows a JavaScript alternative. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the date-range field, you should use another column as [`DataNavigateUrlField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.datanavigateurlfield.aspx):

```
DataNavigateUrlField="KeyField"
DataTextField="DateField"
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductInfo.aspx?ProductID={0}"
```

If you don't want to use a `HyperLinkColumn`, you should use a `TemplateField` and add a `Button`:

```
 <asp:TemplateColumn> 
      <input type="button" onclick="location.href='ProductInfo.aspx?ProductID=<%#Eval("KeyField")%>'" value='<%#Eval("DateField")%>'' />
 </asp:TemplateColumn>
```