# Select a row in GridView and pass the record id to the redirected page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've been struggling with this issue for a whole day now and I don't seem to find an answer.

I have a page called PickRecord.aspx where I have dynamically generated columns "Start Interview", "Edit" and "View Record" which will redirect me to the StartInterview.aspx or EditViewInterview.aspx accordingly.

PickRecord.aspx - The GridView is populated with Interviewee names and a button is generated which when clicked on should redirect me to StartInterview.aspx and give me other fields/information in the record selected.

StartInterview.aspx - Contains additional information on the record chosen which needs to be populated with data from the database. I have tried query string, used selectedIndexChanged and had no luck.

Woul'd really appreciate it if somebody can guide me through this. Thanks in advance!

```
PickRecord.aspx


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="470px" Width="660px" HorizontalAlign="Center" SelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <Columns>   
        <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="First Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center">    
        </asp:BoundField>   

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Name" HeaderText=" Last Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center" >    
        </asp:BoundField>   

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Salon_Number" HeaderText="Salon" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center" >  
        </asp:BoundField>   

    </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

PickRecord.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace TSS.Trainer
{

    public partial class Trainer_PickRecord : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    static string id;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbConnection dbConn = new dbConnection();
        string s = Request.QueryString["mode"].ToString();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillMonth(ddl_T_month);
            FillYear(ddl_T_year);
        }

        if (s == "a")
        {

            TemplateField tf1 = new TemplateField();
            tf1.ItemTemplate = new btntemplate1();
            tf1.HeaderText = "Start Interview";
            tf1.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            GridView1.Columns.Add(tf1);

            DataTable dtInterviewee = new DataTable();
            dtInterviewee = Salon_WebService.populateInterviewee();
            GridView1.DataSource = dtInterviewee;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        else if (s == "b")
        {
            TemplateField tf2 = new TemplateField();
            TemplateField tf3 = new TemplateField();
            tf2.ItemTemplate = new btntemplate2();
            tf3.ItemTemplate = new btntemplate3();
            tf2.HeaderText = "Edit";
            tf3.HeaderText = "View";
            tf2.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            tf3.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            GridView1.Columns.Add(tf2);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(tf3);

            DataTable dtInterviewee = new DataTable();
            dtInterviewee = Salon_WebService.populateInterviewee();
            GridView1.DataSource = dtInterviewee;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

         void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
            id = row.Cells[0].Text;
         }

    }



    class btntemplate1 : ITemplate
    {

        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {

            HyperLink h1 = new HyperLink();
            h1.NavigateUrl = "Trainer_StartInterview.aspx?x= " +id;
            h1.ImageUrl = "../Images/T_StartIV_small.png";
            container.Controls.Add(h1);
        }
    }


    class btntemplate2 : ITemplate
    {
        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {

            HyperLink h2 = new HyperLink();
            h2.NavigateUrl = "Trainer_Home.aspx";
            h2.ImageUrl = "../Images/Edit_small.png";

            container.Controls.Add(h2);

        }
    }

    class btntemplate3 : ITemplate
    {
        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            HyperLink h3 = new HyperLink();
            h3.NavigateUrl = "Trainer_ViewRecord.aspx";
            h3.ImageUrl = "../Images/View_small.png";

            container.Controls.Add(h3);
        }
    }
}
```

}

StartInterview.aspx

```
<div id="T_StartInterview_formHeader" class="fh2">
        <center>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCreate_Date" runat="server" Text="Create Date : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelCD" runat="server" Text="December 05, 2011 "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUpdate_Date" runat="server" Text="Update Date : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUD" runat="server" Text="December 09, 2011 "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCreatedBy" runat="server" Text="Created By : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCB" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("First_Name") %>' class="lblSizeR"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUpBy" runat="server" Text="Updated By : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUB" runat="server" Text="Sharon Miller " class="lblSizeR"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFName" runat="server" Text="First Name : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFN" runat="server" Text="Michelle"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLName" runat="server" Text="Last Name : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLN" runat="server" Text="Rusk"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPh" runat="server" Text="269 123 1234"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="E-Mail : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMail" runat="server" Text="xyz@visiblechanges.com" class="lblSizeR"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: white">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSalon" runat="server" Text="Salon: "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSal" runat="server" Text="Memorial City Mall" class="lblSizeR"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Trainer_StartInterview.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TSS.Trainer
{
public partial class Trainer_StartInterview : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How are you adding the querystring? What's in the code-behind of StartInterview.aspx. 

Also, I'm not sure if you have some URL rewriting scheme going on, but the NavigateURL you assigned to the button is "Trainer_StartInterview.aspx" and not "StartInterview.aspx".

Comment: To answer your question:

Comment: Thanks for your response. To answer your question: in "Trainer_PickRecord" I have added a "GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged Method" that selects the row in gridview. I have also declared a  global variable called 'id' which holds the Id of the record, which I then pass using ----- h1.NavigateUrl = "Trainer_StartInterview.aspx?x= " +id; in the "InstantiateIn" method. I have also included the Trainer_StartInterview.aspx.cs file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the exact issue, but if you are not even hitting StartInterview.aspx page then I would advice you to remove the complicated instantiated in code and replace it with a simple template based column having a button or even a button column. You can check this link for the implementation : [Redirect to specific page when a gridview buttonfield is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686792/redirect-to-specific-page-when-a-gridview-buttonfield-is-clicked)

Comment: Well, my issue is that in PickRecord.aspx, I am trying to get the Row Id of the selected item in the gridview and pass it to the Trainer_StartInterview.aspx page. I am forced to use the InstantiateIn method because the "start iv" button or the edit and view buttons are generated dynamically based on the selection made in the previous pages. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you render them from start but keep them hidden and make visible according to your criteria ?

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. Why did I not think about that! Let me try this. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! You could use a template column and put buttons there. I would say, go for InstantiateIn method only if there is no other way around it and for all practical purposes, you should be able to do this without going for anything advanced in nature.